# Exporting sql query results to csv using bcp

Tags: sql-server, excel, csv, bcp

When I tried to export my query results into CSV file using `bcp` cmd, the export was fine. However my address field is shown only half from my result.

However when I selected the format as 'Text' from 'General', I could see the complete address. Is there any way I can see the whole address by default without any action?

I tried saving the CSV file name with Text format but `bcp` overrides it every time and creates a new CSV file with "General" format. Please guide me to avoid manual intervention.

Comment: Try adding this to your column you want as text. ="column_name"

Comment: My address column name is already like this '"'+ISNULL(Address,'')+'"' As Address

Comment: So add something like ' " '+ '=' + ISNULL(Address,'')+' " '

Comment: It doesn't work.My address is pulling like =xxxx.